# python importing packages from inside another folder

Tags: python, package

I've seen posts related to this one but I am not sure how to handle this kind of problem.

I have a python program and a folder, Missing Bit. Inside Missing Bit I have another folder named Program Files that contains packages that I would like to keep separate. How do I import those packages without raising any errors or problems? (I am a beginner to programming, especially with python)

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a picture of my program layout:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tiy0l2urfhonq7/Untitled.png
LAPI would be inside of the Program Files folder along with the configuration file. I just don't know if it is possible to import a package so far into a file tree

Comment: Can you provide a little more info please

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs what information would you like me to provide?

Comment: To clarify, you want to import from `"Missing Bit"` without importing `"Missing Bit"/"Program Files"`?

Comment: @Freetech: What you have tried already, and what errors you received

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs there you go